# Handlebars templating and dynamic images

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

In my templates I am doing something like

```
<img class="someClass" src="{{imgURL}}">
```

The images are loaded correctly but I get warnings like:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/%7B%imgURL%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is the template appended to the page before being parsed by your templating engine? If so, I don't see any workaround.

Comment: I don't believe so. I am making an ajax call which grabs my external handlebars templates. I cache those templates and later on I have a function that takes the json data and finds the proper template to use as the source and then I compile the source and pass the json data to that compiled template. Is there something about this method that would cause these warnings?

Comment: That's weird then. Well, when you create an image element with the source, the browser will make a request to try to cache it already. If the template is parsed as a string then parsed into DOM elements that shouldn't happen. But anyway, you can ignore that kind of warning, it's just to inform you that a requested file was not found (that's right before you swap the source and it loads again), regular end-users don't have their consoles open while browsing your site.  `=]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're missing a closing quote in your `<img>` but that's not a big deal.
2. Your template is being stored in a hidden `<div>` or similar element that contains HTML.

If you say this:

```
<div id="t" style="display: none">
    <img class="someClass" src="{{imgURL}}">
</div>
```

the browser will interpret the `<img>` as a real image and try to load the resource specified in the `src` attribute, that's where your 404:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/%7B%imgURL%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

comes from. Templates are rarely valid and properly formed HTML so you need to keep the browser from trying to interpret template as HTML. The usual approach is to store the template in a `<script>` with a non-HTML `type`:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <img class="someClass" src="{{imgURL}}">
</script>
```

Then you can say `Handlebars.compile($('#t').html())` to get your compiled template and the browser won't try to interpret the `#t` content as HTML.

Answer (score 8):

None of the answers worked for me. I got it to work by converting the image into base64 and sending that as the img src inside the handlebars template

template.hbs

```
{{#if img_src}}
    <img src="{{{img_src}}}" alt=""/>
{{/if}}
```

source.js

```
data = {
         img_src: base64img.base64Sync('./assets/img/test.png');
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it is late but here is how to do what you want :

```
var view = Ember.View.create({templateName: 'myTemplate', myPicture: 'http://url_of_my_picture.png'});

view.appendTo('#myDiv');

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myTemplate">
    <img {{bindAttr src="myPicture"}}>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that using triple brackets will work fine.

```
<img src="{{{your source}}}" alt={{{your alt}}} />
```

Comment: The question was asked in 2012, over 5 years ago. Are you sure that this new answer is applicable to the 2012 version of handebars.js?

Comment: This is still working fine in 2024