# How to use a value as a key for another lookup in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have a JSON that looks like:

```
var x = {
    default_image: 1,
    urls: {
        1: { catalog: "yyy.jpg" },
        2: { catalog: "zzz.jpg" }
    }

}
```

In my Handlebars template I want to render the url depending on the value of the key `default_image`.

In the above example, I want to render the value `x.urls[x.default_image].catalog`

Say I have a template looking like this:

```
<img src="{{what_goes_here}}" />
```

What goes inside? (Or should I use some kind of helper function for this?)

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531743/handlebars-templating-and-dynamic-images

Comment: That lookup is not something that you view should do. Have the default URL already calculated.