# Handlebars.js: {{ this.url }} not working within <img src="{{ this.url }}">

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, wordpress-rest-api

Handlebars.js won't parse the code if i place it within a / etc.
As soon as it is outside, it works fine.

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        {{#each this}}
        <h1>{{title.rendered}}</h1>
        <div>{{content.rendered}}</div>

        <img src="{{url}}" alt=""/>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

I expected to get

```
<img src="http://localhost/image.jpg" alt=""/>
```

but the output was following:

```
<img src="{{url}}" alt=""/>
```

Everything else seems to work. The loop too.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531743/handlebars-templating-and-dynamic-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <img class="someClass" src="{{url}}">
</script>
```

> Templates are rarely valid and properly formed HTML so you need to
>   keep the browser from trying to interpret template as HTML. The usual
>   approach is to store the template in a  with a non-HTML type:

Or use triple brackets

`<img src="{{{your source}}}" alt={{{your alt}}} />`

> ```
> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash",
> ```
>
> {{{
>       {{{foo}}}

Source: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Found via: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars-site/issues/28

Comment: the tripple brackets {{{ this.url }}}